# Compile error with GCC when using variable arguments

Tags: c, gcc, variadic-functions, gcc4.8

I have a function that works with variable arguments and looks like this:

```
static int getIntValue(const int min,const int max,va_list *vl)
{
   int   listValue;

   listValue=va_arg(*vl,int);
   if (listValue<min) listValue=min;
   else if (listValue>max) listValue=max;
   return listValue;
}


unsigned long init_if_list(int *var,va_list vl)
{
   char *listTag;

   listTag=va_arg(vl,char*);
   if (!strcmp(listTag,INIT_SHOWUI)) initValues.uiFlags=getIntValue(INT_MIN,INT_MAX,&vl);
```

This code compiles well with Windows/VisualStudio 2012 and "older" GCC versions (like 4.7 on CentOS 6). But it fails when I try to compile it with GCC 4.8.4 / Ubuntu. Here I get following error:

```
error: cannot convert '__va_list_tag**' to '__va_list_tag (*)[1]' for argument '3' to 'int getIntValue(int, int, __va_list_tag (*)[1])'
   if (!strcmp(listTag,INIT_SHOWUI))                initValues.uiFlags=getIntValue(INT_MIN,INT_MAX,&vl);
```

Anybody an idea what is wrong here? Why does GCC complain?

Thanks!

Comment: It's 2016. Why the varargs?

Comment: Don't pass the `va_list` argument as a pointer? If you look closer at the error message you will see that it already *is* a pointer, i.e. it's type-alias (`typedef`) for `__va_list_tag*`, so you don't need to use pointers to emulate pass-by-reference.

Comment: Lightness Races in Orbit: because DLL-interfaces still need to be plain C, C++ interfaces depend on exact version of compiler.

Comment: There are lots of things wrong with the way you use the va_list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always pass `va_list` by value, never by pointer.

Therefore:

```
static int getIntValue(const int min, const int max, va_list vl)
```

and

```
initValues.uiFlags=getIntValue(INT_MIN, INT_MAX, vl);
```